Formatting Specific Portions of a Gmail Email Created with Apps Script
I'm trying to find a way to create emails using Google Apps Script and format specific words or phrases (not the whole body) in the email body. I want to automate creating some emails that have specific formatting needs.
I want to be able to make a header for a section that is bolded, underlined, and size 13.5pt and a sub-header that is bolded, size 10pt, with font color #990000. I also want to be able to do a bulleted list.
Can I do this with html or is there a way to create the email body with the specific formatting I want in a google doc and then copy and paste this into a email with apps script?
I've used apps script for a while but have not used the gmail classes and am unfamiliar with the html language. From what I've seen online you can format the whole body with html but I have yet to find information on formatting specific portions of the body.

Send Email with Specific Format
Formatting specific parts of an email is possible by using sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options). Here's a sample script that does I want to be able to make a header for a section that is bolded, underlined, and size 13.5pt and a sub-header that is bolded, size 10pt, with font color #990000. I also want to be able to do a bulleted list. of the question. Kindly check if it works on your end.

Script:
  function sendEmail() {
  var htmlBody = "";
  htmlBody += "<h1 style='font-size: 13.5pt; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline'>Header</h1>";

  htmlBody += "<h2 style='font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; color: #990000'>Sub-header</h2>";

  htmlBody += "<ol>";
  htmlBody += "<li>Item 1</li>";
  htmlBody += "<li>Item 2</li>";
  htmlBody += "<li>Item 3</li>";
  htmlBody += "</ol>";

  var options = {
    htmlBody: htmlBody
  };
  GmailApp.sendEmail("enter-your-email", "Subject", "", options);
}

Output:


If this resolves your issue, please click the accept button (checkmark icon) on the left and consider upvoting the answer. This helps others in the community with similar questions find solutions. If you don't see the accept button, feel free to let me know.
